# Using makefile, LD_PRELOAD to executable file

Tags: c, linux, shell, makefile

I have two files, "abc.c" and "run"

and I want to make a executable binary file which perform below two intstructions

```
gcc -m32 -O2 -Wall -DRUNTIME -shared -fPIC -o a.so abc.c -ldl
LD_PRELOAD="a.so" ./run
```

I tried to use makefile in linux, but failed.

Can I use makefile to make executable binary file ?

Comment: Doing this in a makefile will work just fine. (You'll want two targets for this.) What have you tried?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to use LD_PRELOAD, this is usually used to override a system library. a.so doesn't sound like a system lib to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, makefile should be used for compilation. For automating the shell commands, you can use a shell script.

Maybe, in your case, you can write a shell script, which will call the `make -f <SomeMakeFile>` command first to compile and generate the library (`.so`) and then run the target binary with alogwith the `LD_PRELOAD` instruction.

Comment: All true but having a makefile target to run something in a test/debugging fashion isn't unreasonable.

Comment: I agree with Etan, `make test` is a very viable approach. I've used it a lot at various companies.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
all: a.so

test: a.so
        LD_PRELOAD="a.so" ./run

a.so: abc.c
        gcc -m32 -O2 -Wall -DRUNTIME -shared -fPIC -o a.so abc.c -ldl

clean:
        rm -f a.so
```

Save this in a file called `Makefile`. Note that the indentations MUST be a single tab - stackoverflow ruined that in their output above.
There are now 4 targets, calling just `make` will generate the shared library, explicitly calling `make test` will run your test. If needed, `make test` will build the library first.
I was tempted to throw in some more flexibility, but that was not what you asked for...